# userdel による ユーザの削除が currently used by process と表示され失敗する

Tags: linux, gitlab

お世話になっています。
gitlabを一度アンインストールしようとして削除手順を踏んだのですが、gitユーザが削除できません。

```
userdel -r git
```

を行うと「user git is currently used by process 662」と表示されるので、内容を調べたところ、

```
ps aux | grep git
```

の結果、

```
runsvdir -P /opt/gitlab/service log:  logrotate: warning: unable to open supervise/pid.new: file does not exist runsv logrotate: fatal: unable to start ./run: file does not exist runsv logrotate: fatal: unable to change directory to ./log: file does not exist runsv logrotate: warning: unable to open log/supervise/pid.new: file does not exist svlogd: pausing: unable to rename current: /var/log/gitlab/unicorn: file does not exist
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/gitlab-workhorse -listenNetwork unix -listenUmask 0 -listenAddr /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/socket -authBackend http://localhost:8080 -authSocket /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket -documentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public -pprofListenAddr
```

等々出て来るのですが、/var/opt/gitlab/等々は既にアンインストール済なのと、まだサーバーに明るくないので何が引っ掛かっているのかわからずにいます。

また、「su - git」で入ると、

```
su: warning: cannot change directory to /var/opt/gitlab: No such file or directory
-sh-4.2$
```

と表示されます。

やりたい事は「gitユーザを一度削除したい」（作り直したい）のですが、何が引っ掛かって削除できないのでしょうか？

アンインストールは、以下の手順を踏みました。

```
gitlab-ctl stop unicorn
gitlab-ctl stop sidekiq
gitlab-ctl stop nginx
yum remove gitlab-ce
rm -rf /opt/gitlab
rm -rf /var/opt/gitlab
rm -rf /etc/gitlab
rm -rf /var/log/gitlab
rm -f /etc/yum.repos.d/gitlab_gitlab-ce.repo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

当該プロセスを終了させます（再起動したタイミングなどで問題のプロセスは無くなりますから解決していると思いますが）。

プロセス番号 662 のようですので、

```sh
ps -f 662
```

などとし、このプロセスが何なのか調査します。
大事なプロセスでなければ、

```sh
kill 662
# これで駄目なら
kill -kill 662 # など
```

で終了させます。
正当な手順を踏んで終了させないとマズそうなプロセスであったなら、別途考えなければなりませんが、おそらく Gitlab 関係のプロセスであり、それはアンインストールしてしまっていますから、`kill` して構わない、あるいは `kill` するしか無い可能性が高いです。